# tensorflow- how to keep column label name when one-hot-encoding?

Tags: python, tensorflow, feature-engineering

When trying to get the label of a column in order to one hot encode it by using `tensorflow`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# some data
d={'column1':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'column2':['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], 'column3':[1, 2, 3, 4]}


# convert from pandas df to TensorSliceDataset
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(df))

# convert to specific feature_column
just_types = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
      'column1', ds.column1.unique())

# apply one hot encoding
type_one_hot = feature_column.indicator_column(just_types)
type_one_hot
```

The next error arises:

> AttributeError: 'TensorSliceDataset' object has no attribute 'column1'

I know this is possible with `pandas` but is it possible to get a dataframe in `tensorflow` and then change it to pandas again in a way that kinda looks like this by using `tensorflow`? :

```
#   column1_a  column1_b  column_c  column_d
#       1           0          0        0
#       0           1          0        0
#       0           0          1        0
#       0           0          0        1
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what exactly you would like to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I wonder if it is possible to one-hot-encode a specific pandas df column with tensorflow and then reconvert it from tensorflow to pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using function **from_tensor_slices** in my opinion is an overkill in this example. Just to point out two functions

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(df))

# going back to pandas DataFrame

df_reversed = tfds.as_dataframe(ds)
```

And CategoryEncoding option

```
layer = tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding(num_tokens=4, output_mode="one_hot")
layer([1,2,0, 3])
```